# Should I use viewing, watching or reading comics?

Tags: word-choice

> I have been reading/watching/viewing this comic for a long time.

Which one should I use?

*Update:* In the sentence above, **comic** refers to: *a periodical containing comic strips.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Comic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comic)***:

> - (also mainly US comic book) a magazine or book that contains a set of stories told in pictures with a small amount of writing.

- You  "read" a comic.

Examples:

From [Teaching through texts:](https://books.google.it/books?id=m1qGAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22read%20a%20comic%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMypO30IvPAhUJBsAKHRa9ASIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22read%20a%20comic%22&f=false)

> - (There is, of course, more choice ***in how you read a comic,*** than there is in how you read traditionally laid out narrative.) These signs and hand gestures seemed to make explicit and complex intellectual processes that were going on around the comics....

From [The New Subversive online cartoonists](https://books.google.it/books?id=RuQwX_yX0SEC&pg=PT73&dq=%22read%20a%20comic%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA3tX30IvPAhVmD8AKHSFRA3UQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=%22read%20a%20comic%22&f=false) :

> - PEANUTS By Charles Schulz,  good for readers who hold unusual viewpoints ***to be able to read a comic and say*** "Yes! I'm not alone!" And I think you can take someone and push